# Cox Box transformation normal distribution

Tags: statistics

I'm pretty bad on statistics but i'm actually working on production and we do a lot of measurements to test if the product is correct or not. It seems to me that it would be a great idea to have an estimation of population parameters thank to a sample for each measurement.

When the measurement observations are normally distributed, I have no problem to extract from the sample the population parameters like the average and the standard deviation. At least I think that I have no problem.

Nevertheless, when the observations are not normally distributed, it seems really hard to find a way for each distribution to find the population parameters and actually at the end, i would like to do a python script for estimating the different parameters. And it seems pretty bad to me to do a lot of cases according to the distribution...

So i saw the Cox box transfomation on internet that allow us to transform by using the correct formula a "not known distribution " into a normal distribution. Nevertheless I do not understand how it works... And I have some difficulties to find informations about Cox Box transformation on Internet.

Suppose I have random variable X which do not follow a normal distribution. Then i do a Cox box transformation, suppose I use the log transformation and it works. Y = Log(X). So Now I have a random variable Y which follows the normal distribution. Here is the beginnning and i clearly do not understand all the principles. Thank to the Cox Box transformation, I m now able to extract from the sample population parameters on Y (not X) because Y is normally distributed. Nevertheless, do we agree for saying that the probabality P(Y<0.95) is not equal to the probability of P(X<0.95) ??? If I'm wrong could you please explain me this point ? It seems to me that if I have population parameters on Y, I should do the inverse Cox Box transformation for having the population parameters on X ? Am I wrong ? Could you please help me by writing some maths ...

Thank you vey much and have a nice day ! :D

Comment: $P(Y<0.95)=P(logX<0.95)=P(X<exp(0.95))$

Comment: Or perhaps you meant $P\left(\frac{Y -\mu_Y^{\,}}{\sigma_Y^{\,}} < 1.645\right) =0.95 \implies P\left(X < e^{ \mu_Y^{\,}+1.645\sigma_Y^{\,}}\right) =  0.95$

Comment: Thank you very much :D yeah it was a bit confusing to use the value 0.95 and write P(Y<0.95)... Yeah, Henry you re right this is what I wanted to mean :D